# Domain Password change causes Outlook saved POP passwords to fail

Tags: domain, outlook, password, pop3, accounts

I have a user that repeatedly has this issue. A 3 month password change is enforced on the domain, but when the user changes his, Office 2003 will re-ask for the POP account password, even though it has not changed. Entering the correct POP account password causes it to repeatedly fail. If you go and change the POP password and enter the new one, then it is fine.

He's the only one with this issue, but also the only user with both an Exchange and POP account.

Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the user's POP3 account on the exchange server? If so, the POP3 credentials will change along with the domain account.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, no the POP3 account is hosted completely separate to the Exchange server, its just an addition email account they require.